# How to restore a VirtualBox image given the .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox

## Background

I have VirtualBox on Linux and recently the drive with the system files failed on me. I'm able to use the Live CD to view the files of the storage drive, and through this, I can copy my data files to another computer while I work on this one.

**How do I load the .vdi in another computer (or in this case, the fresh install of Ubuntu)?** I see many samples online of how to export it, but it assumes the host is currently working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to copy the .vdi file and the .xml machine definition that uses that file (usually in a directory nearby). If you had performed any snapshots you will need to copy those files as well.

Once you have copied those files to the new computer, you will need to open the VirtualBox.xml file (possibly in $HOME/.VirtualBox) and manually add in the appropriate lines for the .vdi file you copied (so it shows up in the storage manager) and the machine definition is added to the list of available virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox File->Export Appliance

on the new mechine File-> Import Appliance